# Linear programming instance/Online solver

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Does anyone know what in this [online linear programming problems solver](http://simplex.tode.cz/en/lnlltusmn8r#steps) AFTER clicking on the green button SOLVE is the meaning of the numbers below $t$, i.e. in the last column: $\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{120}$ in this instance of a linear program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem like the numbers needed for the minimum ratio test, see [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Leaving_variable_selection) of the simplex method description on Wikipedia.

Comment: They say: "... A calculation shows that this occurs when the resulting value of the entering variable is at a minimum." Which calculation is it and if resulting variable OR rather the ratio?

Comment: @user122424 Look at "#4 Simplex table 1". If you choose $y_1$ as the pivot row, then for $b$ you get $-1/9$ in the second row, which corresponds to the solution $x_1=1/9$, $y_2=-1/9$, $x_2=x_3=x_4=y_1=0$. Since $y$ has to be nonnegative, that is not allowed. By choosing the smallest ratio, you ensure that you will not get a negative number in the $b$ column. The calculation is column $b$ divided by the column of the entering value (elementwise).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I do not follow how explicitly have you obtained $-1/9$ for $b$ and the other numbers in your comment's second row?

Comment: @user122424 could you create a pivot at the position I mentioned, carry out the row reduction steps, and share the resulting tableau so I can explain the numbers?

Comment: I think that the pivot for our bad situation is in the #4 table the row with $y_1$ but I do not know which column?

Comment: @user122424 sorry, it is the highlighted column in "#4 Simplex table 1" (with values 9, 10, 1, -19), and you turn the 9 into a pivot (instead of the 10).

Comment: To understand fully the situation, why now do you begin with "sorry"? Have you previously said something incorrectly?

Comment: @user122424 I said that out of politeness because it was not clear from my other comments.

Comment: Now I can see why in the column  $b$ one will get $-1/9$. BTW, what the letters i.e. the names for columns $t$ and $b$ stand for?

Comment: $t$ is the ratio test number (not standard notation), $b$ is named after the right hand side of the original problem (since you typically write a problem as $\min \{ c^Tx : Ax \geq b, x \leq 0\}$).

Comment: What rule determines which column is selected in that example in online solver: $x_1$ at #4,
$x_1$ at #5,
$x_2$ at #6 and
$y_1$ at #7 ?

Comment: Especially in #7 why it is selected $1/12$ ?

Comment: @user122424 you can select any column for which there is a negative number in the objective column (in z' for phase 1, in z for phase 2). Typically you pick the most negative number. Iterations #1-#7 are to get $y$ out of the basis (so maximize the z' objective). Then in #7 it is observed that $y$ is no longer in the basis, so some rows/columns get removed. Then #8 is an optimal tableau.